# Customizing the Okta Footer

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am trying to customize the footer that contains the support links etc. There is an option to enable/disable but I want to customize it so that I can add my own links or code in there.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Okta only supports enable and disable of the footer.

You can, however, host a custom page and include an `<iframe></iframe>` with the source as *https://{your-org}.okta.com/app/UserHome?iframe=true&iframeControlHideAll=true*. 
Example:

```
<body>
<iframe src="https://{your-org}.okta.com/app/UserHome?iframe=true&iframeControlHideAll=true"; frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe> 
</body>
```

Another option is to completely build your own portal with a custom look and feel using the [Okta API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/).